# Find a value in a set of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, set, c++14, shared-ptr

I have a set of `shared_ptr` and would like to find a value in it:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<int> IntPtr;

struct Compare {
  bool operator() (const IntPtr& a, const IntPtr& b) {
    return *a < *b;
  }
};
std::set<IntPtr, Compare> s;

auto x = std::make_shared<int>(3);
s.insert(x);

bool found = s.find(std::make_shared<int>(3)) != s.end();
```

It's working, but not efficient - it need to new a temp pointer every time when trying to find a value.

Is there any other way for it?

Looks like [Searching in a set of shared_ptr<QString>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228895/searching-in-a-set-of-shared-ptrqstring) has some ideas that might help?

Comment: _"it need to new a temp pointer every time when trying to find a value."_ What do mean?

Comment: It's the argument of `s.find`, the `std::make_shared<int>(3)`

Comment: There's also `std::find_if`, and eventually you could use an unordered set?

Comment: @DanielJour: `std::find_if` does a linear search, whereas `std::set::find` does a binary search (`O(n)` vs `O(log(n)`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed, my concern was more to find out whether the allocation is the main issue here.

Comment: @DanielJour That's a good point. I always find it it difficult to choose between simpler code or more efficient code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(In C++14) Make your comparator [a *transparent* one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators) and define additional logic for comparing stored `shared_ptr`s with `int`s:

```
struct Compare 
{
    using is_transparent = void;
    //    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

    bool operator() (const IntPtr& a, const IntPtr& b) const
    {
        return *a < *b;
    }

    bool operator() (const IntPtr& a, int b) const
    {
        return *a < b;
    }

    bool operator() (int a, const IntPtr& b) const
    {
        return a < *b;
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ce54daa6d0743f)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, learned something new today. That is, I'd read about transparent comparators but it didn't stick. I did not associate it with any practical use case.

Answer (score 0):

With a single-threaded program you can reduce the overhead to a single global allocation:

```
using Int_ptr_set = std::set<IntPtr, Compare>;

auto find( int const v, Int_ptr_set const& values )
    -> bool
{
    static IntPtr p = std::make_shared<int>( 0 );
    *p = v;
    return values.find( p ) != values.end();
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

For threading you might consider making the above a method of a class, with `p` as a member, then make a thread-local static of that class.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create the int with `v` instead of `0` and avoid the `*p = v;` statement?